# Bittrex API Invalid Signature Response With Python

Tags: api, python-requests, hmac, sign

I am trying to view my open orders through the Bittrex API but all I get is an `INVALID_SIGNATURE` response.

I'm using Python 3.6. Here is my code:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests

apikey = '12345'
apisecret = '56789'

nonce = str(time.time())

url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?&apikey=' + apikey + '&nonce=' + nonce

signature = hmac.new(apisecret.encode(), url.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
hdrs = {'apisign' : signature}

r = requests.get(url, headers = hdrs)
print(r.json())
```

I'm expecting a response like:

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "Uuid" : null,
            "OrderUuid" : "09aa5bb6-8232-41aa-9b78-a5a1093e0211",
            "Exchange" : "BTC-LTC",
            "OrderType" : "LIMIT_SELL",
            "Quantity" : 5.00000000,
                …
        }
    ]
}
```

But instead I get:

```
{'success': False, 'message': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE', 'result': None}
```

I know my keys are correct, and using purposely incorrect keys changes the INVALID_SIGNATURE response to 
APIKEY_INVALID. I've tried to pull other information such as "getbalance", "getorderhistory", etc., but they all give the same result.

I've found many variations of the code above, but each one I try ends with the same result. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but after a week of searching, I still don't know why it isn't working.

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your system time is what is should be? The invalid signature can because your nonce is not correct.

Comment: I ran your code and got `{'success': True, 'message': '', 'result': []}`.

Comment: did you add a space behind `apisecret` or `apikey`?

Comment: I tested it on other computers as well as Google Compute Engine, and they gave the same response, so I think that rules out a system time problem. Also I checked for any typos and errors with the keys and they are correct. Again, if I intentionally add a typo to the keys, the response changes to APIKEY_INVALID so I'm sure they are correct.

Comment: I just got it to work but I don't know why. I tried getting open orders using a php script and an older set of keys and it worked. I tried this older set of keys in a Jupyter Notebook and it didn't work, but when I restarted the kernel it did. Bittrex permissions for the keys seem to be the same and I had no typos, so I still don't know what the problem was.

Comment: I just came across this as I had a similar problem. I wasn't using the encode method as your are but I just did and it works. Thank you!